# Authorization header when following redirects

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, browser

When following redirects for a 303 response, in a Chrome, IE, and Firefox, the `Authorization` header is included.
That's an issue when a request to an internal service respond with a signed S3 URL in the `Location` header.
S3 will respond with a 400 response, and can't figure out which authentication method to use.

**Request to internal service**

```
GET INTERNAL_SERVICE HTTP/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Origin: https://example.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,da;q=0.7,de;q=0.6
Authorization: Bearer g6YQjOy3BDu32es8xKdMRNpcQ2Fkrh5NG7y5fDs5
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authority: example.com
Host: example.com
Connection: close
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2018 08:55:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Server: nginx
location: S3_SIGNED_URL
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-                        
Requested-With
Access-Control-Max-Age: 28800
```

**Request to S3**

```
GET S3_SIGNED_URL HTTP/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Origin: https://example.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,da;q=0.7,de;q=0.6
Authorization: Bearer g6YQjOy3BDu32es8xKdMRNpcQ2Fkrh5NG7y5fDs5
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authority: example.com
Host: BUCKET_NAME.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Connection: close
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-request-id: REQUEST_ID
x-amz-id-2: AMZ_ID
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2018 09:06:41 GMT
Connection: close
Server: AmazonS3

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
   <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
   <Message>Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm     
query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization 
header should be specified</Message>
   <ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
   <ArgumentValue>Bearer g6YQjOy3BDu32es8xKdMRNpcQ2Fkrh5NG7y5fDs5</ArgumentValue>
   <RequestId>REQUEST_ID</RequestId>
   <HostId>HOST_ID</HostId>
</Error>
```

Is there a way to instruct the browser to ignore the `Authorization` header, or force S3 to ignore the header?

Comment: What if you use a different redirect code, like 302 or 307?  It seems quite wrong in any event for the browser to send an `Authorization` header cross-origin... is CORS configured on the bucket?

Comment: We've tried both 303 and 307 and it's the same issue.
And CORS has been configured

Comment: If CORS is enabled, here's my next thought... even though I didn't initially *think* it should matter, if you have `<AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>` (or `*`) in the CORS configuration for the bucket, maybe there's an interaction there.  https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cors-api-specification-redirect

Comment: We have tried removing the header from AllowedHeader, but the browser still sends the header, and then we get CORS conflicts instead.

The browser doesn't seem to send a preflight request to S3 at all.

Comment: @MortenHauberg were you ever able to solve this?  We're facing the exact same issue.

Comment: @Vinnie, no unfortunately not

Comment: It's 2021 and I still cannot find an answer to this question. This is an incredibly insecure design to redirect Authorization headers to a cross-origin resource, and with S3 being in use more and more, I continually hit this issue.

Comment: Facing this too. This must be a big security hole, don't understand why nothing is happening ...

Comment: It's 2022 and I still cannot find an answer as well ...

Comment: After spend too much time, i found solution in angular.  Solution is Interceptor! Prevent(delete) lazyUpdate header.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a kludge, but there is a workaround to this situation by using CloudFront to front S3.  More information posted here: [ReactJS- remove HTTP header before redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861144/reactjs-remove-http-header-before-redirect/51252434#51252434)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by configuring my back-end to support an alternative auth header (X-App-Authorization) and pull its token from that.

This is obviously not ideal because (1) the app has to now make use of a non-standard header at least for the affected endpoint and (2) the app's authorization token is still being "leaked" to AWS.

If these issues are a non-starter for your application, you can solve the problem by using something like NGINX's `X-Accel-Redirect` and having your reverse proxy stream the S3 download transparently. This is of course less efficient than redirecting to S3 directly.

Comment: This approach also works if you're using the cognito authoriser integration with API gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

Create an interceptor like below.

```js
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  intercept(req, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (req.headers.lazyInit.headers.get('x-skip-auth') != null) {
      debugger;
      req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers });
      var indexAuthorization = req.headers.lazyUpdate.indexOf(
        req.headers.lazyUpdate.filter(x => x.name == 'Authorization')[0]
      );
      delete req.headers.lazyUpdate[indexAuthorization];

      req.headers.lazyInit.headers.delete("x-skip-auth");
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Lets begin a request :)

```js
   this.http.post(
        'url',
        {},
        {
          headers: {
            "x-event-id" : eventId,
            "x-skip-auth" : 'true'
          },
        }
      )
```

What are we doing?

1. Interceptor looking for "x-skip-auth" header key.
2. Interceptor removes the Authorization header from header if request has "x-skip-auth" header.

Good Luck!