# How to not pass authorization header in httr for redirects

Tags: r, redirect, authorization, libcurl, httr

Issue mentioned and followed up at:
https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/626
https://community.rstudio.com/t/possible-to-drop-authentication-header-on-redirects-in-httr/44358

This issue happens when:

1. httr sends a GET call to a URL which requires an "Authorization" header
2. the API constructs a redirect to a pre-signed URL which is returned as the response to the original GET request, for which no authentication is required
3. the httr client sends the same "Authorization" header on the redirect URL as it did on the URL of the original GET call
4. a 401 is returned because the bearer token is not valid for the redirect URL

It seems that "Authorization" headers should not be sent when a redirect is followed.
But this is a common issue even in e.g. browsers (so this might be broader than httr):
[Authorization header when following redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49253245/authorization-header-when-following-redirects)

The following example works (http redirect to https), but requires writing a function separate from httr.
Can httr handle this type of use case directly or is it best practice to write custom wrappers for this ?

Example (adapted from https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/626) :

```
library(httr)
# Ensure curl version is higher than 7.58: https://curl.se/docs/CVE-2018-1000007.html
curl::curl_version()$version
# Call URL without following to redirect
resp <- GET(
  "http://github.com",
  config(followlocation = FALSE),
  authenticate("user", "pwd", type = "basic")
)
# Check response of URL, which contains the redirect within the location field
resp
redirected_url <- headers(resp)[["location"]]
# Call redirect URL without authentication
resp_redirect <- GET(redirected_url)
```

Console outputs:

```
> curl::curl_version()$version
[1] "7.60.0"

> resp
Response [http://github.com/]
  Date: 2022-08-24 09:11
  Status: 301
  Content-Type: <unknown>
<EMPTY BODY>

> redirected_url
[1] "https://github.com/"

> resp_redirect
Response [https://github.com/]
  Date: 2022-08-24 09:12
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Size: 301 kB
```

Comment: So this code works but you just don't like it? I mean, if you reported it to the `httr` GitHub and they marked the issue as resolved by this method, then it seems to be fair to assume this is what they recommend. This seems like more of the exception than the rule so the default behavior make sense.

Comment: @MrFlick This post was meant as a how-to, as the only info I could get was on the github page but not on stackoverflow. 
But if there is an in-built approach from httr to handle this, it would be best to use it instead of this custom wrapper. 
And I am not sure if the exception is to pass or not to pass the authorization header from the original URL to the redirect URLs.